# working on sentimental analyzer using naive bayes on imdb dataset and following is get reviews function taking reviews from ds. but giving error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

When i was trying to use get_reviews fn it is giving me error at `f.read.decode()` saying `str` has no function decode and when I removed `.decode()` it again giving me error which I specify down the 1st error.

```
               def get_reviews(dirname,positive=True ):
                     label = 1 if positive else 0
                     reviews = []
                     for filename in os.listdir(dirname): 
                        if filename.endswith(".txt"):
                        with open(dirname + filename,"r+") as f:
            
                           review = f.read().decode('utf-8')#we decoding text as utf 8
                           review = review.lower().replace("<br />"," ")
                           review = re.sub(token_regex,"",review) 
            
            #returning a tuple of the reviews text and lable for 
            #wheather it a positive or negative review
                           reviews.append([review,label])
            
                  return reviews
```

error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-92e2ebb79bdf> in <module>()
----> 1 positive_reviews,negative_reviews=extract_reviews()

<ipython-input-5-233b24b569a3> in extract_reviews()
     22             tar.extractall()
     23             tar.close()
---> 24     positive_reviews = get_reviews("aclimdb/train/pos/",positive = True)
     25     negative_reviews = get_reviews("aclimdb/train/neg/",positive=False)
     26 

<ipython-input-5-233b24b569a3> in get_reviews(dirname, positive)
      7             with open(dirname + filename,"r+") as f:
      8 
----> 9                 review = f.read().decode('utf-8')#we decoding text as utf 8
     10                 review = review.lower().replace("<br />"," ")#converting it to lower case and removing spaces
     11                 review = re.sub(token_regex,"",review) #and surbbing the sentenses having special characters

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

It is the second error i got when i try to remove .decode() and if remove .decode() then it gives me following error.

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-92e2ebb79bdf> in <module>()
----> 1 positive_reviews,negative_reviews=extract_reviews()

<ipython-input-7-6a7844747fcf> in extract_reviews()
     22             tar.extractall()
     23             tar.close()
---> 24     positive_reviews = get_reviews("aclimdb/train/pos/",positive = True)
     25     negative_reviews = get_reviews("aclimdb/train/neg/",positive=False)
     26 

<ipython-input-7-6a7844747fcf> in get_reviews(dirname, positive)
      7             with open(dirname + filename,"r+") as f:
      8 
----> 9                 review = f.read()#we decoding text as utf 8
     10                 review = review.lower().replace("<br />"," ")#converting it to lower case and removing spaces
     11                 review = re.sub(token_regex,"",review) #and surbbing the sentenses having special characters

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in decode(self, input, final)
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
     22     def decode(self, input, final=False):
---> 23         return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
     24 
     25 class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 803: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `utf-8-sig` while reading the file instead of `utf-8`. That should solve the problem.